# How can I create a function in sympy with a latex name?

Tags: latex, sympy

I wish to do something like the following in sympy

```py
import sympy as sp
psi = sp.Function("\psi")
psi
```

Displays \psi instead of Ψ.

However that doesn't work.  Does anyone know how to name a sympy function with greek symbols?

Comment: Sadly, I believe this is a bug. Your `psi` is of type `UndefinedFunction`. The `LatexPrinter` class implements the `_print_UndefinedFunction` that should render objects of type `UndefinedFunction`, but it appears it never gets called. Please, consider opening an issue on SymPy.

Answer (score -1):

You haven't said what environment you are using to display the function. This is from isympy in a unicode enabled terminal:

```
In [26]: psi = Function('psi')

In [27]: x = symbols('x')

In [28]: psi  # not ideal
Out[28]: psi

In [29]: psi(x)  # works
Out[29]: ψ(x)

In [30]: latex(psi)  # what would be used in a Jupyter notebook
Out[30]: '\\psi'

In [31]: latex(psi(x))
Out[31]: '\\psi{\\left(x \\right)}'
```

Comment: I am using Jupyter notebook and sympy version 1.9.  Yes it works if (x) is added to the end of it but otherwise not.  I have tried putting $ signs around it and it still doesn't work